# How to implement quicksort using recursion

Tags: python, quicksort

I am practicing using recursion to implement the quicksort algorithm. I am getting the error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Here is the error:

```
In [2]: run quicksort.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Desktop/algo/quicksort.py in <module>()
     27 
     28 test = QuickSort()
---> 29 print(test.partition([7, 2, 1, 8, 6, 3, 5, 4], 0, 7))

~/Desktop/algo/quicksort.py in partition(array, start, end)
     20     def partition(array, start, end):
     21         if start < end:                       # this is enough to end recursion
---> 22             pos = QuickSort.partition(array, start, end)
     23             QuickSort.quickSort(array, start, pos - 1)
     24             QuickSort.quickSort(array, pos + 1, end)

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

~/Desktop/algo/quicksort.py in partition(array, start, end)
     20     def partition(array, start, end):
     21         if start < end:                       # this is enough to end recursion
---> 22             pos = QuickSort.partition(array, start, end)
     23             QuickSort.quickSort(array, start, pos - 1)
     24             QuickSort.quickSort(array, pos + 1, end)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Here is my current code (I use a class so other people can know what algorithm I am implementing):

```
class QuickSort:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Quick Sort"
    @staticmethod
    def quickSort(arr, start, end):
        pivot = arr[end]
        i = start-1
        for x in range(start, end):
            if arr[x] > pivot:
                continue
            else:
                i += 1
                arr[i],arr[x] = arr[x],arr[i]
        for y in range(end, i + 1, -1):
            arr[y] = arr[y-1]
        arr[i + 1] = pivot
        return arr.index(pivot)
    @staticmethod
    def partition(array, start, end):
        if start < end:  # this is enough to end recursion
            pos = QuickSort.partition(array, start, end)
            QuickSort.quickSort(array, start, pos - 1)
            QuickSort.quickSort(array, pos + 1, end)

test = QuickSort()
print(test.partition([7, 2, 1, 8, 6, 3, 5, 4], 0, 7))
```

So here "quickSort" basically performs the first operation. After that, "partition" will use recursion to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

quickSort should be calling partition (versus partition calling quicksort). Example single function code, with partition code included in quicksort function. This example also limits stack space to O(log(n)) by only using recursion for the smaller part, and iteration (loop) for the larger part. Worst case time complexity is still O(n^2).

```
class QuickSort:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Quick Sort"
    @staticmethod
    def quickSort(a, lo, hi):
        while(lo < hi):
            pivot = a[hi]             # Lomuto partition
            i = lo
            for j in range(lo, hi):
                if a[j] < pivot:
                    a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i]
                    i += 1
            a[i],a[hi] = a[hi],a[i]   # swap pivot to a[i]
            # recurse on smaller part, iterate on larger part
            if(i - lo <= hi - i):
                QuickSort.quickSort(a, lo, i-1)
                lo = i+1
            else:
                QuickSort.quickSort(a, i+1, hi)
                hi = i-1

test = QuickSort()
a = [7, 2, 1, 8, 6, 3, 5, 4]
test.quickSort(a, 0, len(a)-1)
print(a)
```