# Python - Quick Sort Recursive - How to solve stack overflow?

Tags: python, overflow, quicksort, memoization

I'm doing an assignment and need to write a Quick Sort function to sort a (n x 3) matrix according to a certain key.

Say for example the user inputs the key [2,0,1]. This means the program has to sort the third column first and if there's any equal value it goes and checks the first column to decide the sorting. If values still are equal, it then goes to the second column.

Example:

```
key = [2,0,1]

matrix = [["0","1", "1"], ["0","1", "1"], ["1","1", "2"], ["2","0", "1"], ["2","2", "0"]]
```

Expected result:

```
[['2', '2', '0'], ['0', '1', '1'], ['0', '1', '1'], ['2', '0', '1'], ['1', '1', '2']]
```

I wrote the following code using recursion. It works just fine for a matrix of size less than 1000. If I have a bigger matrix, it gives me a stack overflow error due to Python constraints.

I looked up and realized I may use memoization technique to overcome this problem. Does anyone know how to implement such a thing on my code?

```
def QuickSort (matrix, key, start = 0, end = None):

    if end is None:
        end = len(matrix)-1
    if start < end:
        p = partition(matrix, start, end, key)
        QuickSort(matrix, key, start, p - 1)
        QuickSort(matrix, key, p + 1, end)

    return matrix


def partition (matrix, start, end, ordekeym):

    pivot = matrix[end]
    i = start

    for j in range (start, end):

        if matrix[j][key[0]] < pivot[key[0]]:
            matrix[j], matrix[i] = matrix[i], matrix[j]
            i = i + 1

        if matrix[j][key[0]] == pivot[key[0]] and len(key) == 2:
            if matrix[j][key[1]] < pivot[key[1]]:
                i = i+1

        if matrix[j][key[0]] == pivot[key[0]] and len(key) == 3:
            if matrix[j][key[1]] < pivot[key[1]]:
                i = i + 1
            if matrix[j][key[1]] == pivot[key[1]]:
                if matrix[j][key[2]] < pivot[key[2]]:
                    i = i + 1
                if matrix[j][key[2]] == pivot[key[2]]:
                    break

    matrix[i], matrix[end], = matrix[end], matrix[i]
    return i

print(QuickSort(matrix, key))
```

Comment: If you have working code and are looking for general improvements, the question is more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) – make sure to check what is on topic: [question guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) first.

Comment: Link to [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56914188/56925739#56925739) that only uses recursion for the smaller partition, while iterating (loop) for the larger partition. For an iterative implementation that uses a stack, the larger partition indexes are pushed onto the stack, and the smaller partition handled immediately. In both cases, the general rule is to quick sort the smaller partition first. Note that the example is Lomuto partition scheme, [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) is usually faster.